# Assert a type must match interface, but preserve original type

Tags: typescript

I want to express that a variable matches a type but retain it's exact type; i.e. that the exact type of that variable extends the interface but is its own type. For example:

```
interface TypedLeaves<T> {
  [k: string]: TypedLeaves<T> | T;
  [k: number]: TypedLeaves<T> | T;
}

const x: TypedLeaves<number> = { foo: { bar: 5 }, baz: 8 };
// the following line will complain that x.foo might be a number;
// but I already know it's not!
// I want `x` to be checked against `TypedLeaves<number>`, but not
// lose the specificity of its type without the annotation.
const y = x.foo.bar + x.baz;
```

I could probably do this by removing the type on `x` and then creating a dummy variable that actually doesn't matter, like so:

```
// this variable is just for type checking
const z: TypedLeaves<number> = x;
```

But I'd rather not create dead code just for the purpose to do this check.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a clean way to do this, on option is to create a generic function that performs the check.

```
interface TypedLeaves<T> {
    [k: string]: TypedLeaves<T> | T;
    [k: number]: TypedLeaves<T> | T;
}

function createTypedLeaves<TLeaf>() {
    return function <T extends TypedLeaves<any>>(o: T) {
        return o
    }
}
const x = createTypedLeaves<number>()({ foo: { bar: "5" }, baz: 8 });
const y = x.foo.bar + x.baz;
```

The disadvantage beside the useless function is that since we need to have an explicit argument for the leaf type (because otherwise typescript would just create a union an not give an error). Because we want to specify `TLeaf` but want the compiler to infer `T` we would need a function that returns a function to make it work at least until we get [Named type arguments & partial type argument inference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/23696) in 3.1. Or create a dedicated function for each type (aka hardcode `TLeaf = number`)

The other option beside a variable to do the check is to use a type to help with the check, which will not crate code at runtime as types are erased:

```
type CheckTypedLeaves<TLeaf, TTypedLeaves extends TypedLeaves<TLeaf>> = TTypedLeaves;
const x = { foo: { bar: 5 }, baz: 8 };
type xCheck = CheckTypedLeaves<number, typeof x>
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, guess there isn’t a better way after all but great to hear some ideas. Hope TypeScript maintainers consider this use case at some point!